# How to convert Yaw,Pitch and roll values to CGPoint iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I want to convert Yaw,Pitch and Roll values to CGPoint inorder to draw shapes .But the CGPoint consists of two float values don't know how to add yaw value to cgpoint.My code

```
 float ratio = 125/25.0f;
 CMQuaternion quat = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
 CGFloat roll = radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 -   2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z)) ;
 CGFloat pitch = radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z));
 CGFloat yaw = radiansToDegrees(2*(quat.x*quat.y + quat.w*quat.z));
CGPoint point=CGPointMake(roll*ratio,pitch*ratio);
```

Can anyone please provide me some information regarding this....
Thanks in Advance...